Demai - Baker / Shopkeeper / Wholesaler - which has profit and young customers?
[Mishna Demai 2 4] brings 3 cases:

A) Bakers הנחתומים separate תרומת מעשר (and חלה).
B) Shopkeepers החנונים separate תרומת מעשר and מעשר שני (and חלה).
C) Wholesalers המשפיעין don't separate anything.

רע"ב explains that B) Shopkeepers separate more, because 1) they profit more, 2) they have children customers.
החנונים. שמוכרים מעט מעט בחנות, אינן רשאין למכור את הדמאי, הואיל והן משתכרים הרבה עליהם מוטל לתקן. אי נמי מפני שרגילין למכור לתינוקות שלא יאכלו התנוקות דבר שאינו מתוקן:
[Mishna Demai 5 1] brings 1 case, of a baker הנחתום who apparently doesn't separate anything.
רע"ב explains that this baker is a wholesaler, like case C) above, in contrast to the baker in case A) above who is not a wholesaler. He further explains that A) bakers who are not wholesalers separate more, because 1) they profit more, 2) they have children customers.
הלוקח מן הנחתום. כשהנחתום מוכר במדה גסה הלוקח ממנו חייב לתקן מה שהוא לוקח והנחתום פטור. והא דתנן לעיל בפרק ב׳ שהנחתומים חייבים להפריש כדי שיעור תרומת מעשר וחלה, התם מיירי במוכר במדה דקה שמפני שהוא משתכר הרבה הטילו עליו לעשר, אי נמי מפני התינוקות שלוקחים ממי שמוכר בדקה כדי שלא יאכלו טבלים הטילו עליו לתקן. מדה גסה ודקה מפורשים לעיל ספ״ב:
What confuses me, is that the רע"ב uses the same 2 reasons to explain the most strict case B) Shopkeepers, and A) bakers who are not wholesalers.
Is this just a question of degrees, but it applies to both cases to some extent?

Full explanation of the Mishna Demai 5:1 vs. 2:4 can be found in peirush hamishnayos Kehati after 5:1 which takes 2 pages in small letters.  It is a big sugia in Yerushalmi and meforshim.

I think תוי"ט addresses the question in 2:4-
תוי"ט כדי תרומת מעשר וחלה. מפורש בריש פ"ה. ומ"ש הרע"ב מתוך ששוטרי המלך וכו'. גמ' פ"ק דיומא (ט.). ולקמן בריש פ"ה מפרש הרע"ב דהכא בנחתומים המוכרים במדה דקה עסקינן, ומהני תרי טעמי דמפרש הכא בחנונים, לכך חייבוהו בתרומת מעשר וחלה כמו שכתב שם, ופטרוהו ממעשר שני מתוך ששוטרי וכו' כמו שכתב הכא. ולא קפדינן אתינוקות בטבול למעשר שני בדמאי:
It sounds like there are two separate reasons to be מיקל- All bakers are subject to price controls, so they are פטור from מעשר שני (including A and C).
And storekeepers have profit and children customers, so they are חייב in תרומת מעשר and חלה (including just A and B).
If correct that means that this comment:
רע"ב החנונים. שמוכרים מעט מעט בחנות, אינן רשאין למכור את הדמאי, #1 הואיל והן משתכרים הרבה עליהם מוטל לתקן. #2 אי נמי מפני שרגילין למכור לתינוקות שלא יאכלו התנוקות דבר שאינו מתוקן:
Even though it seems to be explaining why case B, החנונים, is more חמור than case A, הנחתומים - is actually explaining why A and B is more חמור than case C. So confusing דיבור המתחיל in the רע"ב on 2:4.
